# Using itertools for arbitrary number of nested loops of different ranges with dependencies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, functools

Given a list of upperbounds: B1, B2, .. BN;
Dependency Functions: f1, ..., fN-1,

I'm wondering if there's a recipe using itertools or other classes in python for:

```
for i1 in range(0, B1):  
    for i2 in range(f1(i1), B2): ...
         for iN in range(fN-1(iN-1), BN)
             dostuff(i1, i2, ... iN)
```

Where there are N levels of nesting?
I want to use this helper function like this:
**dependentProducts(Bs, fs, dostuff)**,
which returns a list or iterable

Ideally, the implementation would be iterative instead of recursive.

Comment: Funny question. Do you have real world application of that? ;-)

Comment: Why do you prefer it iterative?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Probably because recursion in python is slow and in some cases you do end up breaking the recursion limit...

Comment: @Bakuriu Unfortunately I don't care about such speculations.

Comment: @Laurent I want to use it as a tool in experimental mathematics. Generating sequences helps me build intuition =D. Yes, I prefer iteration because of stack frame buildup... Of course recursive solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: @qedpi Up to how many levels might there be?

Comment: @Laurent As for applications, an example would be generating valid parenthesis sequences iteratively, by using the indices as left bracket locations.

Comment: @StefanPochmann The number of levels will grow with the sequence length, which can be long.

Comment: @qedpi Will there be many levels/ranges with zero or one elements? Cause otherwise this thing is exponential and you won't get very far...

Comment: @StefanPochmann, yes, it would be exponential in most cases, I'm relying on the dependency functions to limit the blowup. If a recursive solution doesn't have to increase the time complexity by a huge factor, I am impartial.

Comment: @Bakuriu With nested looping constructs versus recursion, you will run into intractability issues long before you hit the stack limit. If each sequence  only has 2 items then you'll have to compute more than 10^300  combinations before you hit the stack limit (~1000). For reference the number of atoms in the known universe is ~10^80.

Comment: @Dunes That's assuming the only calls on the stack are from that function which is almost never the case. If you start writing everything in recursive style you'll see that it doesn't take that much to reach 1000 stack frames...

Comment: @Bakuriu That's a premature optimisation. Just because it could be a problem, doesn't mean it is. How frequently will this technique be used? How many levels are going to be used each time? All in all both those numbers are likely to be low, and the stack will be fine. Maintaining the iterative style of this technique will require more effort than the recursive style. The code should be written recursively, and *if* the stack limit is hit, *then* change to an iterative version.

Comment: @Dunes Have a look at my answer, I'd say it actually doesn't take much effort. Though I happily admit that I kinda built it from the recursive version I had in my head :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iterative solution using @LaurentLAPORTE's setup. Put this code right under his and it should work. My `args` is a stack of the arguments fed into `dostuff` whenever it's full. The actual solution is the middle part, top and bottom parts are just testing.

```
stefan = []
def dostuff(*args):
    stefan.append(list(args))

args = [-1]
while args:
    n = len(args)
    args[-1] += 1
    if args[-1] >= B[n-1]:
        args.pop()
    elif n == len(B):
        dostuff(*args)
    else:
        args.append(F[n](args[-1]) - 1)

assert expected == stefan
```

Comment: Thanks to both you and @Laurent LAPORTE ! As you wanted a demo of use, you can do the following valid brackets generation with a simple dependency: https://bpaste.net/show/666281c848e9 Now imagine what one can do with different ones! =D

Comment: @qedpi If you're using it like that, then better replace `outputs.append(g(*args))` with `yield g(*args)` and remove the rest of the `outputs` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what you want:

```
B = [10, 15, 20, 5]

F = [lambda x: x,
     lambda x: x * x,
     lambda x: x * 2 - 5]

def dostuff(i0, i1, i2, i3):
    print((i0, i1, i2, i3))

expected = []
for i0 in range(0, B[0]):
    for i1 in range(F[0](i0), B[1]):
        for i2 in range(F[1](i1), B[2]):
            for i3 in range(F[2](i2), B[3]):
                expected.append([i0, i1, i2, i3])
```

I found a recursive solution like this:

```
def iter_rec(found, fL, bL):
    if fL and bL:
        ik = found[-1] if found else 0
        fk = fL[0]
        bk = bL[0]
        for i in range(fk(ik), bk):
            for item in iter_rec(found + [i], fL[1:], bL[1:]):
                yield item
    else:
        yield found

# prepend the null function to ensure F and B have the same size
F = [lambda x: 0] + F

current = [item for item in iter_rec([], F, B)]
```

We have the same result.

```
assert expected == current
```

Comment: To request a clarification you should use *comments*. If you needed to show that code you could have posted it in a gist (or similar service) and link it into your comment.

Comment: What do you think of this recursive solution? For an iterative solution may requires an additional stack (a `list`)…

Comment: Thanks, I believe it works, could you elaborate on what is required for an iterative solution?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Thanks for the setup, I'm referring to it in my answer, so please don't break it :-D

Comment: Python3 offers `yield from` construct  instead of looping over a generator and yielding, eg `yield from iter_rec(troulala)`